# linux/shell command to control screen brightness in android

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, linux-kernel, android

I am working on a kiosk project using an android tablet.If there is no input power to the kiosk for a long time then, the tablet will eventually shutdown.In order to auto-reboot the tab when the power comes back I modified the code in my tabs battery animation file(ipod) using:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
sleep 300
/system/bin/reboot
```

However,during the sleep period(shown above),the tabs screen remains in the ON state (and hence takes longer retries for the tab to charge and bootup).I need to turn the screen OFF.
What is the command I should use prior to the sleep command to turn my tabs screen OFF during the charging/bootup stage. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple command to turn off the display

`xset dpms force off`

And to turn on the display you can pass `on` instead of `off`.

**UPDATE:**

If your screen is not turned off after executing this command then DPMS(display power management signalling) is not enabled in your system.You can enable that by following command `xset +dpms`

**Method 2**

First Identify your display using the following command

`xrandr -q | grep " connected"`

**OUTPUT**

```
    VGA1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
```

Here VGA1 is my display in the same way you may get LVDS1 or any other display which you have connected.Take that display name and pass it to the below command.

`xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 0.4`

0.4 refers to screen brightness.It ranges from 0.0 to 1.0(you can pass 0.0).

Comment: I tried using 'xset +dpms' and 'xset dpms force off' before the sleep command in my file,however I was not able to turn the screen off.When I used 'echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/leds-mt65xx/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness' the brightness of the screen went low,however on using echo 0 instead of echo 1 I was not able to turn off the screen completely.Can you please tell me what value of echo will make the screen go off completley.PS on using echo 0 using adb I was able to make the screen off though.

Comment: Pls kindly assist me.

Comment: @Basher51 : Please hv a look at the updated answer.